# Charter for text, normal math font for math

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I want to use Charter (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/charter/) as my font for all the text, but I want to use the normal math-font for my math. Can this be achieved?

Comment: charter has no math so you'll have it by default ...

Comment: My math changes when I use \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} which is mentioned in the link I posted.

Comment: but I see now that \usepackage{charter} solves my problem.

Answer (score 7):

https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/charterbt/ proposes

```
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
```

but to use Charter with no implications on the math, using

```
\usepackage{charter}
```

is the right thing to do.

Comment: Tried it (2020), this has to be loaded after `amssymb` and `amsmath`. Also I had to install `ly1`, as mentionned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196214/95423

Comment: Perhaps we should now use [`XCharter`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcharter) than `charter`.