# problem with mathdesign-font and texnansi.enc

Tags: fonts, texlive, font-encodings

I have a problem with the font bitstream-charter.

> less dummy.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} %my font!
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
 aaaaaa
\end{document}
```

pdfLatex fails to produce a PDF with the following error:

```
pdflatex dummy.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./dummy.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 34 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize10pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mathdesign.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/mdbch.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/mdbch.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdfont.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdsffont.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdttfont.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/ot1mdbch.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch/t1mdbch.fd)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)) (./dummy.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdacmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbcmr.fd) [1{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./dummy.aux) )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file texnansi.enc): cannot open encoding file for read
ing
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

- all necessary packages are installed!
- other fonts work nicely (tested `\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}`)
- using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: There is no reason to ever use the texnansi encoding (and your example code does not use it) do you get that error from the posted code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Make sure you test that code specifically to see if you still get the error. As @DavidCarlisle says, there is nothing in your code which would try to use the encoding in the error message so it seems likely that your MWE does not really reproduce the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! However, this MWE produces such an error! I posted the entire output below:

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:Try the code. `texnansi.enc` _is_ used by pdflatex.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I'm on holiday, I don't doubt that it is being used, but there can't be any good reason for that can there?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's used in the mapfiles. `md-chr8y CharterBT-Roman " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bchr8a.pfb`

Comment: @MartinSchröder which is... strange:-)

Answer (score 9):

Install the package [ly1](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ly1). I just had the same problem and this package solved it for me. I'm sure a more knowledgeable user will be able to explain why.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Actually it _is_ an answer, as `texnansi.enc` is contained in the `ly1` package (at least in TeXlive 2014).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Thanks for the information ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: LY1 and texnansi refer to the same encoding but no new documents should be using that encoding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `texnansi.enc` is loaded during font embedding in the PDF file, because of the entry `md-chr8y CharterBT-Roman " TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont " <texnansi.enc <bchr8a.pfb` in `pdftex.map`, which is a bit surprising; but apparently the T1 encoded virtual font is defined in terms of an LY1 encoded font.

Comment: **This solved my problem**! After installing ly1, everything works fine!  
@DavidCarlisle: How else can I use this font then?

Comment: @Johannes as a user, probably nothing:-) But the font package shouldn't be using LY1 in this way.

Answer (score 2):

As well as installing [ly1](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ly1) (in `$TEXMFHOME`), I had to run `updmap` with the `--force` option in order to generate `~/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`.

Answer (score 0):

texnansi.enc is missing from fonts/enc/dvips/base copy it into there, texhash, and your font generation will work

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a source where to get it. Or where to find it, if it is part of a TeX distribution. Also, welcome to our site!